# Child class as return type for a class method

Tags: c++, class, methods

I have a C++ class which is meant to be inherited. All its children will inherit a method:

```
class Record {
public:
    RETTYPE* all();
};

class Child : public Record {
    int age;
    char *name;
};

int main() {
    Child boo;
    Child boos* = boo->all(); // Pointer to array of Children
    return 0;
};
```

How can I make a method return (a pointer to) itself? I can't just say `Record all();` as `Child` is not `Record`. The method will never be called on `Record`. Always on some class inherited from `Record`.

Comment: It is you who has to tell us why you put the method all() to the base class. What for? If just for code reuse I think you should rethink that. If for some polymorphic behaviour make it virtual. Child is a type of Record so it can return a Record* but C++ supports return type covariance

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way

```
class Record {

};

template<class T>
class RecordOf : public Record {
public:
    T* all();
};

class Child : public RecordOf<Child> {
    int age;
    char *name;
};
```

Each subclass now has an all method that returns the exact type.  You can put methods that are virtual and have the same signature in subclasses in `Record` and ones that depend on exact type in `RecordOf`.

It's called the Curiously Recurring Template pattern

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern